# Sort order products in categories by custom value attribute first in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, product-attribute, sorting

I want to sort products with custom value (1) numeric attribute. In toolbar.php:

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
        $this->getCurrentOrder(),
        $this->getCurrentDirection()
    );
    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('recomendado_vistas', 1);
}
```

but this not work, it is possible to sort product with custom numeric value (1) attribute first?

Answer (score 0):

If Have you tried using

```
$this->_collection->setOrder('recomendado_vistas', 'ASC');
```

or if recomendado_vistas values are mix(number, char etc) you can set temporary that not 1 to other value and sort it

```
$this->_collection->addAttributeToSelect('recomendado_vistas', 'left');
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("CASE WHEN recomendado_vistas != 1 THEN 9999 ELSE recomendado_vistas END ASC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY FIELD` in your collection

Sample code:

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
        $this->getCurrentOrder(),
        $this->getCurrentDirection()
    );
    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(recomendado_vistas, 1)"));
}
```

You can pass multiple values in it if you want, like this:

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(recomendado_vistas, 1, 3, 6)"));
```

Make sure your collection is getting your columns `recomendado_vistas`. You can debug your query using this code:

```
echo $this->_collection->getSelect();
```

Comment: i tried but it does not work, and logs do not give error, the page display normal order in all categories and attribute "recomendado_vistas" is set because i tried "$this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('recomendado_vistas','asc');" and it works but i need only this attribute with value (1), any ideas?